# There is an error in xml document when deserializing xml response to object

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I am trying to deserialize an xml response from a web service. This is the response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <ConvertToTypeResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <ConvertToTypeResult>8959459395</ConvertToTypeResult>
        </ConvertToTypeResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I try to deserialize the above xml to this envelope.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ConvertToTypeResponse")]
public class ConvertToTypeResponse
{

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ConvertToTypeResult", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    public int ConvertToTypeResult { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xmlns")]
    public string Xmlns { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body")]
public class Body
{

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ConvertToTypeResponse", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    public ConvertToTypeResponse ConvertToTypeResponse { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope")]
public class Envelope
{

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body")]
    public Body Body { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "soap")]
    public string Soap { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi")]
    public string Xsi { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsd")]
    public string Xsd { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

But I get the this error `There is an error in XML document (1, 40).`

```
IRestResponse response = _client.Execute(_request);
var c = response.Content;
if (response.IsSuccessful)
{
    XmlSerializer secrializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
    using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(c))
    {
        var test = (Envelope)secrializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

I have checked the structure but I struggle to find any mismatch in the model classes. Is it possible the first line of the xml `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` is the problem as there is no provision for it in the model classes.

Comment: There appears to be a missing closing angle bracket on the end of `ConvertToTypeResponse ` - which the StackOverflow syntax highlighting has picked up.

Comment: Furthermore `ConvertToTypeResult` is unmatched by `ConvertToNubanResult`, which is invalid. If this is really the response being brought back from a web service on which you are relying, this service is broken and returning invalid content.

Comment: @TomW that was  an error when posting the question, I updated now

Comment: Is the "<" really the first character in the response? Maybe there is a space or a BOM in front?

Comment: @KlausGütter Yes, it's the first `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: There are automated ways to generate classes from xml and all its shenanigans,  maybe give one a try

Comment: @TheGeneral That's what I used to generate those classes , I didn't write them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the model classes to include the necessary namespaces fixed the issue

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ConvertToTypeResponse", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
public class ConvertToTypeResponse
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ConvertToTypeResult", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    public string ConvertToTypeResult { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xmlns")]
    public string Xmlns { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class Body
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ConvertToTypeResponse", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    public ConvertToTypeResponse ConvertToTypeResponse { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class Envelope
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public Body Body { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Xsi { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsd", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Xsd { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "soap", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Soap { get; set; }
}
```